# C variadic function mystery

Tags: c++, printf, variadic

I'm finding something strange, but before crying to a compiler bug (!?) I'm very open to let anybody point out whatever I'm doing wrong in the following code... I've isolated the problem, here is a simple program that should print a simple log line, but prints something weird.

Here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

void log(const char *file_name, size_t lnum, const char *func_name, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    char y[2048];
    snprintf(y, sizeof(y), fmt, args);

    va_end(args);

    char x[256];
    snprintf(x, sizeof(x), ":%s:%d:%s:", file_name, lnum, func_name);

    std::cout << x << y;
}

int main()
{
    int idx = -2;

    log(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, "this should be -2!? --> %d <--\n", idx);
}
```

This should obviously print:

```
:**some path**:26:main:this should be -2!? --> -2 <--
```

But to me prints:

```
:**some path**:26:main:this should be -2!? --> -1097326128 <--
```

The big number is somewhat random, changes from execution to execution. Looks like a pointer, everything looks like I'm pointing to wrong stack frame / argument but can't figure out what is wrong...

Thanks anybody! :)

FYI:
g++ (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: `snprintf(y, sizeof(y), fmt, args);` Need to use `vsnprintf` not `snprintf`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hhrx7j3vc